# How to download older versions of Glassfish(3.?.?) and use them in Netbeans (8.0) for testing web applications

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I would like to use older versions of Glassfish for testing my web applications in Netbeans 8.0. Where/how should I download these older versions of glassfish and how should I configure my Netbeans environment to run on the older versions of Glassfish instead of the the one (4.0) which came with my netbeans install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the older versions from the official [glassfish.java.net](https://glassfish.java.net) page:

- Glassfish 3.0.1: https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.0.1-final.html
- Glassfish 3.1.1: https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.1-final.html
- Glassfish 3.1.2: https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2-final.html
- Glassfish 3.1.2.2: https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2.2-final.html

It is sufficient to get the zip file versions.

A mirror and some even older versions can be found on the oracle technetwork: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/glassfish/downloads/index.html

To add the servers in NetBeans go to the `Services` tab and right-click on `Servers` and click `Add Server`. Choose `GlassFish Server` and a name (containing the version number), click `Next` and choose the folder where you extracted the specific version.

[image: NetBeans add Server]

Repeat this for the all the versions you need. You can choose the desired server for each NetBeans project in the project properties (in the `Run` tab).